# Can a derived class access constructor and destructor of base class?

Tags: c++

I know that derived class constructor can pass values to the base class constructor? But can a derived class access constructor and destructor of base class in C++?

Comment: Isn't passing values the same thing as "accessing"?

Comment: Well, why not: `Derived function { Base b(); //constructor b.~b() //destructor }`

Comment: Since derived class doesn't inherit constructor and destructor of the base class, it can only pass values to the constructor but what about destructor?

Comment: @awesomeyi: No derived class cannot access its constructors and destructors because the derived class does not inherit them, only the public and protected members but not constructors and destructor. I tried that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a derived class access a base class constructor ?

Yes.

```
struct Derived : public Base {
   Derived(SomeType some_arg) : Base(something_extracted_from (some_arg)) {…}
```

Your "passing values to the base class constructor" is **the** mechanism by which the derived class accesses a base class constructor.

> Can a derived class access a base class destructor ?

Yes, but this is a very bad idea. Unlike a constructor, a destructor has a name, which means it can be called as an ordinary member function. **You do not want to do this.** The underlying C++ machinery is going to call the base class destructor after the destructor for your derived class returns. The base class destructor will be called twice during destruction if your derived class destructor explicitly calls the base class destructor. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yes, values can be passed to the constructor which is also kind of accessing, but I mean calling the constructor which is not allowed from the derived class and the case is same for destructor as well.

Comment: @nirvana - I am getting the feeling that (a) you don't quite understand how construction and destruction work in C++, and (b) you are asking an XY question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is you are trying to do, and why do you think you need to do it?

Comment: No I was just curious about that. I asked question before I tried, and I tried if if works but it didn't. Thanks for your answer.
`#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
A()
{
cout << "\nconstructor\n";
}

~A()
{
cout << "\ndestructor\n";
}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
void show()
{
    A();
   ~A();
}
};`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to call the destructor as an ordinary function. It's a member function. Not that you should ever do this, but change your `B::show()` to `void show() { A().~A(); }`. Note that the destructor is called twice. That's undefined behavior.